# Create File using c++ in Windows 8.1 Project Template

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-8.1, file-handling, ofstream

I am trying to create and write an HTML file using c++ in Windows 8.1. Ofstream.Open() method is not working. It does not create any file in the given path. And I cant find the path where Storagefolder creates that file so that I can view it. Please help me with this.

Comment: What is the given path? does calling `_getcwd` help  you find the file?

Comment: Please post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve so we can figure out what you are trying. Just saying "it doesn't work, please help" is not enough. Did you use any of the state functions described [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream) to find out whether the `open()` has succeeded?

Comment: You probably forgot to escape the \ or did not use / instead.

Comment: ***Please help me with this*** We have to take wild guesses when you don't show a minimal example. There could be many ways to cause a this not to work.